# Arduino Random Characters sent to Bluetooth TX during Code Upload

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

When I upload code to my Arduino while the TX and RX pins are connected to my HC-05 module, a bunch of random characters are sent to the TX buffer, and when I connect to a device, those characters are sent and mess up communication.  Is there a way that I can clear this buffer after uploading the code?  I've just been disconnecting the wires whenever I upload, but I'd like to find an easier way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you use a serial port to both send data and the program of course you will see it on the other side of the BT... Possible solutions:

- disconnect the BT module every time you want to program the Arduino
- shut down the other BT device (or just disconnect it) when you have to program the Arduino
- shut down the HC-05 (or keep it in reset state) until the arduino says that it is communicating (so use a GPIO to control the reset pin or a transistor to power the BT on at the beginning of the program)
- use a 3-state driver between the HC-05 and the Arduino serial ports (one driver for TX and one for RX) and activate its outputs at the beginning of the arduino program.

I don't like djUniversal's solution because you cannot control what the PC transmits; if, for instance, you decide to use the byte 0xAA to signal the start of the transmission then if the PC sends 0xAA the other device thinks that the Arduino is transmitting. Choosing longer bytes sequences helps, because the sequence becomes less probable, but.....

Moreover you have to send it at EVERY command, not just at the beginning, because you have to reset the arduino to program it (and so the other device is not aware of WHEN to stop considering the data).

Comment: A two byte sequence should generally suffice. Unless he is pushing the limits of transmitting data this should take very little away from his efficiency. The reason I suggested what I did is because he said that the garbage values are having a negative effect. What if there was some data corruption (within normal limits) during a routine transmission? Header files and checks will make is code more robust overall.

Comment: I currently have 1-byte headers at the beginning of each transmission to determine which kind of command it is.  I already tried just not connecting until the program is loaded, but even if I connect the phone later, it will receive the characters the Arduino sent as soon as a connection is made.  Furthermore, it appears the string of garbage characters is the same every time, so I could send a command on the Arduino setup that is not found in the string to signify that it has been loaded.  For now, though, I will go with using the reset pin.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

The only other way around it is to send a header of maybe a couple of bytes each time to send a message. The other program can wait for these characters before it starts to take commands. Until those characters are read from the buffer you would just do a Serial.read() loop to get rid of the garbage.

Also, if garbage characters are going to screw up your program really badly you might want to think about creating some kind of crude checksum also to confirm the correct transmission.

Need help coding? Let me know.